# Remove List elements marked on SparseBooleanArray

Tags: java, list, iterator

So basically I have an array of positions at the `List` that has to be removed. We all know we can't use `for` loop cause once you remove the first one, the positions update for the rest of the items, so the solution is using `Iterator`

My `SparseBooleanArray` has **key for the position on the list** and **value (boolean) to indicate if it should be removed or not.

How can I remove them?

EDIT:

```
// list is a List
list.get(0) // first element
list.get(1) // second element
list.get(2) // third element

// sba is a SparseBooleanArray
// the first element of the sea indicates that the list.get(1) should be deleted
sba.keyAt(0)   // = 1
sba.valueAt(0) // = true
```

Comment: you can use a for loop, you just have to adjust the incrementing variable when you remove an element

Comment: i assume the language in question is Java...?

Comment: and you might offer some code so that others can get a clearer picture of what you've tried so far

Comment: yes, language is java. also updated to give a more visual explanation. I'm actually trying to delete selected items on a contextual action bar on android, but couldn't find how to do that. Other post just say how to get the checked items, so this is where I'm stuck

Comment: looking at the `docs`(http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseBooleanArray.html) and it looks like SparseBooleanArrays have a `delete` method that takes the `key` value, and removes the value at that location.

Answer (score 0):

As OP explains, you must use an Iterator.

The following is actual working code. In a simpler scenario you would deploy only the inner loop:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> fldData;       // Mass data
        
/** De-clutter the mass data arrays according to the SparseBooleanArray */
public void de_clutter(SparseBooleanArray sba) {
    for (ArrayList<Object> objArray: fldData) {
        int ix = -1;
        for (Iterator<Object> iter = objArray.iterator(); iter.hasNext(); ) {
            iter.next();
            ix++;
            if (!sba.get(ix, true)) { iter.remove(); }
        }
    }
}
```